# Run-rime Error 438 for Pivot Table creation

Tags: vba, excel

I'm attempting to make a macro to create a Pivot Table based on a consistent location of Data. However, I'm struggling to overcome this initial challenge. I've been following a guide for the creation of Pivot macros, but error 438 consistently ends the macro. The code seems like it should work, but I can't figure out why it doesn't.

```
Sub StockAdjustmentPivot()

Dim myFirstRow As Long
Dim myLastRow As Long
Dim myFirstColumn As Long
Dim myLastColumn As Long

Set sht = ActiveSheet

Dim mySourceData As String
Dim myDestinationRange As String

Dim myPivotTable As PivotTable

myDestinationRange = sht.Range("T5").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

myFirstRow = 1
myLastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
myFirstColumn = 1
myLastColumn = 11

With sht.Cells
    mySourceData = .Range(.Cells(myFirstRow, myFirstColumn), .Cells(myLastRow, myLastColumn)).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
End With

Set myPivotTable = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="STOCK ADJUSTMENTS REPORT!" & mySourceData).CreatePivotTables(TableDestination:="STOCK ADJUSTMENTS REPORT!" & myDestinationRange, DefaultVersion:="PivotTable1")

End Sub
```

The line which brings up the error is the following:

```
Set myPivotTable = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="STOCK ADJUSTMENTS REPORT!" & mySourceData).CreatePivotTables(TableDestination:="STOCK ADJUSTMENTS REPORT!" & myDestinationRange, DefaultVersion:="PivotTable1")
```

I am attempting to fix this before continuing with the detail of the pivot table.

Thanks.

EDIT

I have split the code to a more manageable size, as per guidance:

```
Dim cache As PivotCache

Set cache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="STOCK ADJUSTMENTS REPORT!" & mySourceData)

Set myPivotTable = cache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination = "STOCK ADJUSTMENTS REPORT!" & myDestinationRange, TableName:="PivotTable1")
```

However, I don't think the cache variable is being defined. Running this presents the following error:
Run-time error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument.

Comment: What error description are you getting with error #438?

Comment: The error description is "object doesn't support this property or method".

Comment: The problem presumably has to do with the values of one or both of the variables referenced in the line that's giving the error.  What's the value of each of them?

Comment: I believe the values are fine, they all generate the correct columns/rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: You have a typo. Change `CreatePivotTables` to `CreatePivotTable`.

---

You have one single instruction doing way too many things:

> ```
> Set myPivotTable = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="STOCK ADJUSTMENTS REPORT!" & mySourceData).CreatePivotTables(TableDestination:="STOCK ADJUSTMENTS REPORT!" & myDestinationRange, DefaultVersion:="PivotTable1")
> ```

That's accessing the `ActiveWorkbook`'s pivot caches collection, using it to create a new pivot cache, and in the same breath using it to create a pivot table.

Excel a `PivotCache` doesn't have a `CreatePivotTables` member - hence, *object doesn't support this property or method*.

Split it up, and use properly declared variables.

```
Dim cache As PivotCache
Set cache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="STOCK ADJUSTMENTS REPORT!" & mySourceData)
```

If that works, then you can use it to create the pivot table - and if it *doesn't* work, at least now you know which part failed (the more you stuff into a single instruction, the harder that instruction becomes to debug):

```
Dim pivot As PivotTable
Set pivot = cache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:="STOCK ADJUSTMENTS REPORT!" & myDestinationRange, DefaultVersion:="PivotTable1")
```

Notice the in-place drop-down ("IntelliSense") that the VBE gives you when you type that `.` dot after `cache`: listening to what the editor is telling you would have avoided this typo.

Comment: Many thanks, have taken you advice. Yet new issues arise... (see edit).

Comment: SO isn't a free debugging service, it's Q&A. This Q was about error 438, this A solves error 438. Please avoid chameleonizing your questions. If you have a new error and can't find examples or references online, feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: @Elsybelsy that said, you'll probably need to verify the value of `mySourceData` (assuming the problem is with the `cache` assignment), and/or include this [and any other relevant bit of] information to reproduce the problem in a new post - see [mcve].